# Call to a member function method() on string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

Estou usando o CodeIgniter e, ao tentar fazer uma pesquisa no meu banco de dados para ver se uma dada linha realmente existe, ele apresenta o erro `Call to a member function checarId() on string`. Segue o código das funções que me retornam esse erro:
Função na classe Responsavel (a matricula é um varchar(20) no BD):

```
    function checarId($mat){
        $cont = 0;
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM responsavel where matricula = '.$mat);
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $cont++;
        }
        if($cont == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Segue agora o código da função que chama a função acima, já na classe Sala para checar se pode ou não adicionar uma linha ao BD:

```
function salvar(){
    $data = array('nome' => $this->getNome(), 'codigoresponsavel' =>$this->getResponsavel());
    $this->load->model('responsavel');
    $this->load->database();
    $existe=$this->checarExistencia($this->getNome());

    $respExiste = $this->responsavel->checarId((string)$this->getResponsavel());

    if($existe && $respExiste){
            $this->db->where('nome', $this->getNome());
            $this->db->update('sala', $data);
    }else if($respExiste){ 
        /*$this->load->model('responsavel', 'resp');
        if($this->resp->checarId((string)$this->getResponsavel())){*/
            $this->db->insert('sala', $data);
        /*}
        else{
            $this->load->view('index');
        }*/
    }else{
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `public function checarId($mat)` ?

Comment: Ainda não havia tentado, tentei aqui e não adiantou

Comment: Qual o nome do arquivo do seu model?

Comment: O metodo $this->getResponsavel() retorna uma string realmente?